# Symbolize any non-digit in String (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, string, symbols, digits

I have the following string output:

```
"[1, 2, 3, *, +, 4, 5, -, /]"
```

How can I symbolize the non-digits characters (i.e. *, +, -, /) and return the following result:

```
[1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
```

Currently, I'm using this method to convert the string:

```
def tokens(str)
    new_str = str.split(/\s+/)
    clean_str = new_str.to_s.gsub(/"/, '')
            #Symbolise clean_str to desired output
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "[1, 2, 3, *, +, 4, 5, -, /]"

str.scan(/[^\[\]\s,]+/)
# => ["1", "2", "3", "*", "+", "4", "5", "-", "/"]

str.scan(/[^\[\]\s,]+/).map {|t| Integer(t) rescue t.to_sym }
# => [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eval(str.gsub(/(?<=\[| )(?=\D)/, ":"))
```

Comment: This answer also worked, but I think the marked answer was easier to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean method returning `true` if the current string is numeric, or `false otherwise`. So basically, you can do this :

```
class String
  def numeric?
    Float(self) != nil rescue false
  end
end

"3".numeric?
#=> true
"+".numeric?
#=> false
"a".numeric?
#=> false
"-3".numeric?
#=> true
```

Then, you can iterate over your list (through `each()` for instance ) and replace the current String (say `a`) with `:a` if `numeric?` returns `false` on it. For this, you have to use the `to_sym()` method.

There may be faster way to do this, but I think the `numeric?()` boolean function is pretty handsome.

Comment: You really don't need to duck punch `String` to get the desired result. Don't encourage this practice for something so trivial.

Comment: @macek : "There is more than one way to do it". I get the result using my method, you get one using a block, great. That's why I love Ruby, you can do it the way you want.

Comment: Just because you can do it, doesn't mean you should. This is what sets *best* practices apart from... *not best* practices...

Comment: It's not your method. You copied/pasted it from [here](http://mentalized.net/journal/2011/04/14/ruby_how_to_check_if_a_string_is_numeric/). Please add the source to your answer next time.

Comment: @Mischa : Thanks for the link, didn't know it. Great minds think alike it seems. And seeing when this thread has been posted, I guess I use this method for a longer time than the poster ;). But well, that's off-topic.

Comment: OK, sorry then. This is still not a good answer though. In addition to macek's remark: TS is asking about digits and your answer is about numerics. Those two things are not the same.

Comment: @Mischa : Well my answer might be a bit off topic if he's sure he only has digits, but I don't like the `match(/\d/)` method since you can have wierd results, for instance if one element of the list is equal to, let's say `666 devil`. My way of doing it will handle this problem, while the regexp matching will simply return `true`. But if he's sure his data are always correct, then yes my answer might be like using a hammer to crush a nut.